# The motion of the particle satisfies $\textbf{v} = \textbf{c}\times \textbf{r}$

Tags: calculus, physics, plane-curves

Why is the path is contained in a circle that lies in a plane perpendicular
to $\textbf{c}$ with centre on a line through the origin in the direction
of $\textbf{c}$

Comment: What will you get if you differentiate this equation with respect to t?

Comment: i dont know how to differntiate a cross product , sorry , do u know how

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149817/derivative-of-cross-product-of-two-vectors)

Comment: since $\mathbf{c}$ is a constant then you only have to differentiate $\mathbf{r}$ thus yielding $\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{c}\times \dot{\mathbf{r}}$

Comment: Notice $$v \cdot c = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dt}( r\cdot c ) = 0 \implies r \cdot c = \text{const}$$ This implies the trajectory lies on plane with $c$ as normal vector. Notice $$v \cdot r = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dt} |r|^2 = 0 \implies |r| = \text{const}$$ The trajectory also lies on sphere centered at origin. Finally,  the intersection of a plane with a sphere is a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$$\textbf{v}.\textbf{r}=(\textbf{c}\times\textbf{r}).\textbf{r}=0\tag{1}$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_product#Scalar_triple_product) and $$\textbf{v}.\textbf{c}=0\tag{2}$$
[Therefore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_vector#Euclidean_vector_spaces) $\textbf{v}\perp\textbf{r}~~\forall t$ and $\textbf{v}\perp\textbf{c}$. 
[$$\frac{d}{dt}(\textbf{r}.\textbf{c})=\textbf{v}.\textbf{c}=0\implies \textbf{r}.\textbf{c}=constant\tag{3}$$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/DotProduct/NumberedEquation6.gif) which is the [equation of a plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane) orthogonal to $\textbf{c}$. 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\textbf{r}^2\right)=2\textbf{v}.\textbf{r}=0\implies ||\textbf{r}||=k=constant\tag{4}$$ which is the [equation of a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) of center the origin lying in the plane $(3)$.