# How to explain a vector crossed with its derivative

Tags: vectors

This is an problem we have to do... I have done a lot of research on this. There is no help in our text book or previous homework. 
It gives:
Show that a vector A(t) is parallel to its A"(t) for t is an element of [t1,t2], then A(t)xA'(t) is a constant vector field for t element of [t1,t2].

Comment: This should not require research. How do you always show some function is constant in the context of a calculus course?

Comment: if you show the first derivative is constant?

Comment: ... if you show the first deriviative is _zero._ (But perhaps that's what you really meant to say.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Recall (or look up) how to express
[the derivative of the cross product of two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149817/derivative-of-cross-product-of-two-vectors)
in terms of the vectors and their derivatives.

**Hint 2:** Evaluate the derivative of $A(t)\times A'(t).$

(If your textbook has not yet covered the derivative of a cross product, you might be expected to *prove* the formula is correct. I hope that is not necessary.)