# Derivative of cross product equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

Recently I got a problem that equated the time derivative of a cross product $$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{P}\times\vec{Q})$$ with a function of time(like $t + t^2$).

Ex. $$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{P}\times\vec{Q})=5t-6t^2$$

My question is, how can you have an equation with a cross product derivative (which is itself a vector) with a function of time?

Comment: Easy: you can't.

Comment: Aren't you missing a bit of the formula ? 2D, 3D ?

Comment: $\vec P\times\vec Q$ is a vector. The derivative of a vector with respect to time is still a vector. On the right hand side you have a scalar. So the equation is vector=scalar, which does not make sense

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt}||\vec{P}\times\vec{Q}||=5t-6t^2$$ makes sense

Comment: What is the source and context where the notation is used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivative of cross-product of two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149817/derivative-of-cross-product-of-two-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

As written the expression makes no sense, maybe the two vectors are in a fixed plane such that also the direction vector for the cross product is a fixed $\hat k$, in that case we should write

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{P}\times\vec{Q})=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(\frac52t^2-2t^3+c\right)\hat k\right]=\left(5t-6t^2\right)\hat k$$

and as a notation we could obmit the $\hat k$.